# Suppressing some map events

Tags: openlayers

When I activate map click event, I want to suppress map move event

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setActive(fasle)` for the drag pan interaction depending on thew way you initialise the `ol.interaction.DragPan` intraction. consider the following snip.

```
var dragpanInt = new ol.interaction.DragPan({});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  interactions : [dragpanInt ]
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-6655.5402445057125, 6709968.258934638],
    zoom: 13
  })
});
//disable it
dragpanInt.setActive(false);
//enable it
dragpanInt.setActive(true);
```